# PIC programmer, need to replace few components

Tags: pic, transistors, programmer

I am building a PIC micro-controller programmer named Brenner8: http://www.sprut.de/electronic/pic/projekte/brenner8/

Although, it needs a BF959 transistor for (Q8), and BAT43 diodes for (D1,D2,D4) As this diagram:

[image: Schematic]

I don't have these components in my country. All I have here: BF759, BF859, BF869, BF871, BF872, BF891, and BF981 for transistor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: BAT43 are Schottky diodes- you can't really substitute a transistor or ordinary diode directly.

Comment: @mahmoud-dh  Since your question is country-specific, it would help if you write location in your profile (preferred) or in the question itself.  May be, there is somebody from your country on this site with knowledge of your local component base.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Likely he is an iranian like me(because for his name).

Comment: @Roh actually i am from Damascus-Syria

Comment: @mahmoud-dh Ok, How you know that you can't find those components?(have you already looked for those components?) we(iranian) have several big froum for electronic that one of them is http://www.eca.ir/forum2/index.php . some iranian us this for programing PIC MCUs: http://www.eca.ir/forum2/index.php?topic=38944.0 if you like to see it I can give you the link of schematic+PCB and HEX file. mabe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the text on the website a BF959 is used because it has a low Cbc. My best guess is that this is important only for PICs that require a fast pulse train on the MCLR pin to get into programming mode (eg. PIC32). You could check the Cbc in the datahseets of the transistors you have and pic a candidate.

For other PICs a normal NPN is probably OK.

For the diode you should use a schottky type, any smalls schotkky will probably do.

Comment: thanks,
but what do you mean by Cbc ? is it (base-collector-current ) ?

Comment: I don't know, my best guess is that it is some capacity which limits the switching frequency.